# \columnwidth in cm

Tags: floats, lengths

I have a silly question - i am using double column style

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt, openany]{book}
```

When I add a figure I usually put in `\columnwidth` and just let LaTeX to stretch it to the full width. Now, for practical reasons I'd like to prepare some figures with fixed width in 1:1 ratio, but for that I'd like to know what the `\columnwidth` is in cm.
Is there a way to find that number?

thanks,
U

Comment: `\printlen[5][cm{\columnwidth}` for example, using package `xprintlen`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `xprintlen` package provides the means to show the length of a dimension register in more 'human' units, such as `cm` or `mm`, which is the default:

```
\printlen[2][mm]{length register}
```

Will use 2 significant figures (which is the default), `mm` as unit of the relevant length register.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xprintlen}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,...,5} {%
\printlen[\x][cm]{\columnwidth}

}
\end{document}
```

[image]